# Asp button click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Very First time when the page loads thing is working fine. When I click the asp button then also the thing works fine. I used button click to call a javascript function using

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hello", "addBadge('notification', 23)", true);
```

this javascript function adds an element to my navigation bar. But the problem occurs from here that when I click that button again the added element gets removed and is added again automatically,i.e. the button click is fired twice. I tried using 
AutoEventWireUp= false
All this is happening in content page of the master page.
Please Help. Thank You.

```js
function createBadge(k) {
    var v = document.createElement("span");
    var t = document.createTextNode(k);
    v.appendChild(t);
    v.className = "badge";
    return v

;
}
function addBadge(p, k) {
    el = document.getElementsByClassName(p)[0];
    if (!el.querySelector(".badge")) {
        el.appendChild(createBadge(k));
    }
    else {
        el.removeChild(el.getElementsByClassName("badge")[0]);
    }
}
```

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the `addBadge` function? I suspect this could be one of those cases of not cancelling an event and causing the page to reload.

Comment: I have added the function @Jacob

Comment: Thanks. You've also mentioned a button, but I'm not seeing that in your code.

Comment: in which event you adding node?

Comment: on button click event in c#

Comment: you have written remove badge in else case. So its quite obvious that badge will be removed when you press the button second time

Comment: but this badge reappears again. And it should not happen.

Comment: What you want is not clear. What i guess that you want the nav element to appear on button click but not to disappear when button is clicked second time

Comment: see in this website stackoverflow, there is an inbox option in navigation bar similarliy i have notification option in my navigation bar. What i want is when i click a server side control button the 'span' tag should get inside the navigation bar and be placed over the notification option and it should get removed when i click again and should not come back until i click it again

Comment: Your function looks fine for that. Try debugging the function in chrome developer tools.

Comment: Can you tell me that Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hello", "addBadge('notification', 23)", true) adds this piece of code permanently to java script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if helps

```
function addBadge(p, k) {
el = document.getElementsByClassName(p)[0];
if (!el.querySelector(".badge")) {
    el.appendChild(createBadge(k));
}
else {
   // el.removeChild(el.getElementsByClassName("badge")[0]);
}
}
```

I have just removed the line of code which was removing the badge from the page

Comment: Add the button1_click method also\

Comment: the first line of code at top is the only code written in button click method